# how to fix the function yield_and_skip

Tags: python

```
def yield_and_skip(iterable):
    x = iter(iterable)
    y = next(x)
    while x:
        if type(y) == int:
            yield y
            for i in range(y):
                y = next(x)
        elif type(y) == str:
            yield y 
            y = next(x)
```

I am writing a generator that takes an iterable as a parameter: it produces every value in the iterable except if it produces an int n, it does not produce (skips) the next n values.

for instance,

```
for i in yield_and_skip([1,2,1,3,'a','b',2,5,'c',1,2,3,8,'x','y','z',2]):
    print(i,end=' ')

prints 1 1 a b 2 1 3 z 2.
```

but instead of

```
1, 1, 'a', 'b', 2, 1, 3, 'z', 2
```

my function prints

```
1, 2, 3, 2, 'c', 1, 2, 8
```

can someone help me to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unrelated to your issue, but your `while x` loop doesn't do what you intend. Iterators are not falsey when they're exhausted. Your code works in current versions of Python because one of the `next()` calls raises a `StopIteration` when the iterable is exhausted, and the uncaught `StopIteration` works as the signal your generator function is done. However, starting in Python 3.7, an uncaught `StopIteration` bubbling out of a generator will be turned into a `RuntimeError`. For future compatibility, you should catch the `StopIteration` and `return` (or run off the end of the function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can fix it, first is increasing the number of iterations in your for loop by one: 
`for i in range(y+1):`.

The second is to just reassign `y` to the next iteration of `x` after the for loop:

```
for i in range(y):
   y = next(x)
y = next(x)
```

Comment: A nice way to do your second suggestion is to unindent the last line, so it's not in the `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the limits of the range in

```
 for i in range(y):
```

to

```
 for i in range(y + 1):
```